# UISearchContainerViewController linker failure in iOS 9.1/Xcode 7.1.1

Tags: ios

I have severe problems implementing `UISearchController` wrapped up in `UISearchContainerViewController` for a universal tabbed bar application.

Basically what I am trying to implement is search like in the Apple music app where `UISearchController` is not set as a `tableHeaderView` but is presented upon tapping a magnifying glass button in the navigation bar.

It's very important that the `UISearchController` is initialised like this: `searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)` not with `nil`, as there are all kinds of scopes and searchable content could be core data and server.

I am currently presenting the `UISearchController` modally which completely screws up the view hierarchy as search happens in `UISplitViewController` installed in one of tabs (both master and detail view controllers).

This is the linker error.

[image: Linker error!]

My deployment target is 9.1 - I have seen on Apple forums [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26085) that somebody else had the same problem.

So is it an Apple bug or I should be looking somewhere in my app?